# Google Billing plan change during grace/hold

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, android-billing, play-billing-library

I'm using Google Billing 5.2.1 on Android with `ProrationMode.DEFERRED` when changing the subscription plan.
Sometimes the users get `The replacement mode is not applicable when subscription is in grace period or account hold` error, apparently when the sub is in grace/hold period.

What's the recommended approach to handling plan change during the grace or hold period?

It's not documented anywhere, but apparently it's illegal to change the plan when the subscription is in grace/hold, although the error is not even shown to a user by the billing flow.

Should I suggest users to cancel the sub and resubscribe with a different plan?
Should I stop using the replacement mode? What would be the behavior without it? (It's not documented either)